# Change layout builder page's title programatically

Tags: layout-builder

I've tried altering the page's title using **hook_preprocess_page_title** and I'm able to get it to work on non-layout builder pages but I can't get it to work on pages that use layout builder.  How can I programmatically change the H1 page title on a page that uses layout builder?

Thanks